# Getting Password?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to get the password of the user when i do Email/Password Authentication...

But when i do getAuth()/onAuth().. The object is just the email,uid,token,etc... but not a password.

The reason i need the password is because i want to be able to change the users password. And to do that you need the users old password as the syntax of the angularfire docs state:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.changePassword({
  email       : "bobtony@firebase.com",
  oldPassword : "correcthorsebatterystaple",
  newPassword : "neatsupersecurenewpassword"
}, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("Password changed successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error changing password:", error);
  }
});
```

Thankyou.

Comment: If you've designed your application properly the only way to know a user's password is to ask them. Do you have a form where the user could supply the old and new passwords?

Comment: It is an extremely bad practice for any service to have access to users' actual passcode. Usually service providers save a key made from the user's password and saves that.
So, as commented above, you need to ask the user for his old *and* new password in order to allow the change.

Comment: Firebase knows the old password, so you just have to ask the user for it and pass the input to `changePassword`. You don't need to know the old password, as Firebase does that check itself

Comment: Oh ok @mjr I completely understand you. Thanks guys you guys helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the password in the database of firebase. Which i wont recommend since you will be vurnable to attacks. But what i would reccomend is prompting the user for the old password. And check if it is write. Then Procced to changing the users password. As explained by Code(Added Sweet-Alert to make it preeety :)) :

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");

ref.onAuth(function(authData) {

    swal({
        title: "Old Password!",
        text: "Write Old Password",
        type: "input",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        animation: "slide-from-top",
        inputPlaceholder: "OldPassword..."
    }, function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue === false) return false;
        if (inputValue === "") {
            swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
            return false
        }
        $scope.originalPassword = inputValue


        swal({
            title: "New Password!",
            text: "Write New Password",
            type: "input",
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            animation: "slide-from-top",
            inputPlaceholder: "NewPassword..."
        }, function(inputValue) {
            if (inputValue === false) return false;
            if (inputValue === "") {
                swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
                return false
            }
            $scope.NewPassword = inputValue

            ref.changePassword({
                email: authData.password.email,
                oldPassword: $scope.originalPassword,
                newPassword: $scope.NewPassword
            }, function(error) {
                if (error === null) {
                    swal("Nice!", "Password Changed Succesfully!", "success");
                }
                else {
                    sweetAlert("Oops...", "Error Changing Password" + error, "error");
                }
            });



        });




        swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
    });


})
```